# How to write the xpath for an element preceded by another element?

Tags: xpath

I want to get the value from an element based on the element preceding it. 
For example, getting the value "YYYY-MM-DD" based on the element "date"

Here is the html snippet:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the value you need to extract is in the input element, you can use the following xpath;

```
//div[contains(text(), 'date:')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'form row')]/following-sibling::input[@id=formData-rest_of_the_id_value]
```

Its better to use id attribute to locate web elements, because it is unique to the web element.

Check [this](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html) tutorial for more on xpath

Answer (score 1):

I used the following xpath

```
//div[contains(text(),'date')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'form-row')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[@class='_textContainer_psmgei']
```

but can there be a better way?

Comment: You can try the following: //div[contains(text(),'date')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'form-row')]/following-sibling::div//input[@type='text']::preceding-sibling::div

Answer (score 1):

**If the element is unique then use :**

```
//div[contains(text(), 'date:')]
```

**If you believe that the parent element is unique and not the target element then**,

You could just do:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'form row')]/div[contains(text(), 'date:')]
```

You don't have to check sibling.

Here // means anywhere in the HTML DOM, / means direct child. So the given locator finds direct child of `div[contains(@class, 'form row')]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think input[@id=formData-rest_of_the_id_value] "rest_of_the_id_value" is auto-generated value and it will change all the time.

I prefer this way

```
//div[contains(text(),'date')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'form-row')]/following-sibling::div//div[contains(@style,'position']
```